# Github API - query to pull completed and failed attempts in one run

Tags: github, github-api

Based on a run_id (5061376665), I want to pull the list of github jobs in one report, including:

1. the successful runs
2. the failed runs.

So far I have found how to get the List jobs for a workflow run, however it only shows me the last and succesful attempt:
[https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/5061376665/jobs](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Bowner%7D/%7Brepo%7D/actions/runs/5061376665/jobs)

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-jobs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-jobs-for-a-workflow-run

Since the run completed in the second attempt, I had to look at the first attempt with this query:
[https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/5061376665/attempts/1/jobs](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Bowner%7D/%7Brepo%7D/actions/runs/5061376665/attempts/1/jobs)

Is there a way to pull the information (completed & failed) from the same run_id (5061376665) without running separate queries?